# Regular expression Regex to extract a string

Tags: regex

Please can somebody help me, I`m new to regex and have no idea how to do this!.

I`m trying to extract from a list which looks like this...

**Joe-Age23-46737-251.aspx

Tim-Age18-46909-451.aspx

Roger-Age41-59768-251.aspx**

What I want is this...

**46737-251.aspx

46909-451.aspx

59768-251.aspx**

so basically anything after the second to last hyphen.

Cheers

Comment: Please add another tag to your question stating the language you're using (because regex features differ).

Comment: Would you mention what's the used programming language (add its tag)? And please mention what have you tried so far, so it should not seems to be "write code for me" question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's translate "everything after the second-to-last hyphen" into regex:

```
(?<=-)[^-]*-[^-]*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=-)  # Assert starting position right after a hyphen
[^-]*   # Match zero or more characters except hyphens
-       # Match a single hyphen
[^-]*   # see above
$       # until end of string.
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fvBreM/1).

Comment: Wow! thank you so much, it worked :)

Comment: Or perhaps simply `\d{5}-\d{3}\.aspx$`

Answer (score 0):

Step1 : Split the string on the basis of hyphen(-) . You will get array of strings.

Step2 : extract the second , fifth and eighth 
and so on( incremented by 3 ).

Step3 : concatinate all the strings formed in step2.